# npx create-next-app@latest is giving errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a new nextjs app but I get a npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty error. Please the image below
[image: the screenshot of the errors]

Its been working fine for the past year I am not sure what really happened.

Please help me out I couldnt find any answers on Google.

```
node version
v19.8.1
npm version
9.5.1
React version
18.2.0
Next version
13.2.4
OS version
Ubuntu 22.04
```

Comment: try doing `npx create-next-app@latest <project-name>`

Comment: gives the same errors

Comment: You are not using the stable version of Node. Switch to `18.15.0` and start over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this first

```
npm init 
npm install create-next-app@latest --save
npm create-next-app <appname>
```

If it's not work you might use stable version of node like 18.15.0 
If you don't know how to switch node version this will help you 
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

And try your step 
hope it's work!

Answer (score 7):

I created an account just to answer this, and the reason why it doesn't work is because you don't have a npm folder/directory in your Appdata/Roaming

C:\Users(YourUser)\AppData\Roaming

then create a folder named npm

so you should have

C:\Users(YourUser)\AppData\Roaming\npm

and there you go when you use npx create-next-app@latest it will now work

Comment: this should be labeled as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, for some reason no NPM folder was created in

> C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Roaming

so i just created that folder then it worked out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the Node Package Manager (npm) to the latest version; you can use the following command:

```
npm install -g npm
```

This command installs the latest version of npm globally on your system. The `-g` flag ensures that npm is installed globally, allowing you to use the updated npm across all your projects.

After running this command, you can verify the installation and check the updated version by using:

```
npm -v
```

This should display the new version number, confirming that npm has been successfully upgraded.

Make sure you have the necessary permissions to install global packages, and if you encounter any issues, consider using a package manager like sudo on Unix-based systems or running your terminal as an administrator on Windows.

Keep in mind that updating npm may also require updating Node.js itself, so it's a good practice to check for the latest Node.js version and update it if needed. You can find the latest version on the official Node.js website: https://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, I tried several things it didn't work. What work was there is no npm folder in AppData/Roaming/ so I created

npm folder in Roaming

.../AppData/Roaming/npm

and it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35430189)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not exactly the same, I got the error ETIMEDOUT instead of ENOTEMPTY, however @Bear's answer led me to the solution and the cause of the error.

I had the version 18.8 of NodeJS, but create-next-app@latest needed >=18.17.0, the message was very clear when doing `npm i create-next-app@latest` while there was just a timeout error when doing `npx --verbose create-next-app@latest`.

The fact is that because my version of node did not match `latest` requirements, it did not find a compatible version of that package on npm.

I just had to install a newer version of NodeJS to fix the error.