# I'm trying to install react and I get this error in command line

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I'm trying to install react and I get this error in command line.

```
C:\Users\PCµ\Desktop\react.PA>npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PCµ\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\PCµ\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PCµ\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-28T13_44_57_213Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Check out this similar issue here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771598/npx-create-next-applatest-is-giving-errors