ShadCN npx commands not working on VS Code, any solution?
I've been trying to run a command to create a Next.js project and I keep getting an error message saying:
> npx shadcn@latest init
  npx shadcn@latest init
      ^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'shadcn'

Also, other commands like:
> npx create-react-app@latest ./ --typescript --tailwind --eslint
npx create-react-app@latest ./ --typescript --tailwind --eslint
    ^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'create'

I'm using Node.js v22.7.0.
and npm v10.8.3
I've uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code, and even tweaked the User Settings JSON, this is my current JSON:
{    
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
    "*.gitpod.io": "linux"
},

    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Node.js": {
      "path": "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
      "args": [] // Add startup arguments as needed.
},
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "/bin/zsh"
},

// Make Node.js the default shell (if the property already exists, update its value).
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Node.js",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Material Theme Ocean High Contrast",
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
}

So, I'm wondering if my settings need some adjustment. If you geniuses could help a brother out, it'd be great.
Edit: I also tried running the command on CMD both in VS Code and outside of it and it returns: Something went wrong creating a new Next.js project. Please try again.
And doesn't add extra context

Have you tried it on a terminal or cmd (if you use Windows) outside of VSCode? Or try to run npx command only to check if there is an error before you create the project

Hey @Ramadita I also tried that, and it returns "Something went wrong creating a new Next.js project. Please try again."

Try to run npm install -g npm to see if there are any more errors

@Ramadita tried it, it returns:
 changed 13 packages in 28s

 22 packages are looking for funding
 run `npm fund` for details.

Then rerun the previous code and it returned the same error

Try installing npx and create-react-app again to make sure the two libraries are installed properly.
npm install -g create-react-app
npm install -g npx

If the problem still exists, please ask again.

both libraries are installed, and the problem still persists

You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77421603/8726313 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/75775558/8726313 if the problem still exist
